# Using & in if batch file commands

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

I have a problem. Lets say that I want to link two IF commands to have an answer.

For example a batch file:

```
@echo off

IF %a%== 123 AND IF %b%== 456 then COMMAND.
```

How can I link the two if's

Answer (score 2):

In batch there's no AND operator, you can emulate it by a series of if-clauses in cascade

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_booleanlogic.php

```
IF %a% EQ 123 (
        IF %b% EQ 456 (
            ' do your fancy stuff...
        )
)
```

Comment: It's best to summarize the applicable part of the link to the current question (in case that site goes down, is edited, etc.).

Comment: Thank You VERY MUCH. THIS IS EXACTLY WHAT I WAS LOOKING FOR. You just helped me a lot!!!

Answer (score 2):

This is all you need, but it can be enhanced to protect against spaces and `&` characters etc.

```
@echo off
IF %a%==123 IF %b%==456 COMMAND
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method, somewhat specific to your particular pair of conditions:

```
IF "%a%.%b%" == "123.456" command
```